# What does this #define statement mean?

Tags: c, floating-point, macros

```
#define CONVERSION_FACTOR (0.78125E-2f)
```

What is the expected result of this macro? I know that `f` is float. What does `E` mean?

Comment: It is simply `0.0078125` or `0.78125 * 10^-2)`

Answer (score 1):

It's called scientific notation or "E notation".
It's a shorthand: mEn would indicate a value of m × 10^n